# Could not resolve property: <"username"> of: com.education.library.model.Customer

Tags: hibernate, dao

I'm trying to write a search, using Hibernate that would run search on two types of vatiables.I have a model Customer, that has properties: Id, name, username,password, genre are String, and int.
I have created "**customerlDao**" and "**customerDaoImpl**". These are given below,.

public interface CustomerDao {

```
public Customer validateUser(String username, String password);
```

}

```
@Override
public Customer validateUser(String username, String password) {
    Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Customer.class);
    Customer customer = (Customer) criteria.add(Restrictions.eq(username, password)).uniqueResult();
    return customer;
}
```

but, Its not working,. The Error message "Could not resolve property: <"username"> of: com.education.library.model.Customer" How I change it..

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with `Restrictions.eq(username, password)`.
You need two restrictions

`Restrictions.eq('username', username)` and `Restrictions.eq('password', password)`.

And you can have an incorrect mapping for a Customer. Please show it too.